# How to get picture url on public profile page of a linked in user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, linkedin-api

The picture url returned by linkedin api is formatted profile picture. It's not the one which is being present on public profile page of user. How can i access this public picture url?

Answer (score 0):

You can get the original photo size adding ::(original) to the picture-urls field like this:

```
https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,num-connections,picture-urls::(original))?format=json
```